# Can not find App.config in DLL when we call dll from client code

Tags: c#, dll, app-config

Below is code in my dll

RemotingConfiguration.Configure("App.config", false);

which give error as could not find App.config.

I called my dll from client app.

I have added same App.config file in my client solution but did not help.

I tried it using MyDll.dll.config but no luck. I am not sure what I am missing here.

Answer (score 0):

Generally a class library / dll uses the config file of the client which is compiled into, for example: `ClientName.config` so the file you want to access at runtime will not be called `app.config` or `yourdll.config`.

If you add the configs you need for your dll into client's app.config you should be fine but your dll itself should not have hard-coded the client name .config string as it would not make it usable from clients with other names.